# Wolfram Cloud University Credentials

Tags: untagged

I had the ambition to use Wolfram cloud for a project but some issues arose.

I am using my Indiana University account, but the cloud only sees my personal account, which only has basic service, and then the cloud only allows storage for two months and fairly short computations. How do I fix the cloud so it recognizes my IU credentials? (I am now bouncing between IU and Wolfram tech support and it seems an answer might take a while.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is about Mathematica's setup and license administration at a university campus and is therefore technically off-topic. Wishing the OP best of luck, though.